# How to display images those are captured from camera on a selected row?

Tags: android, camera

I have list of rows. If I want to select a particular row and in onclick event of "camera" button the captured image should be add to that selected row. But my problem is the captured images are adding to the last row.

```
private void getlist(final ArrayList<Exceptions> exceptionRowsList2) {

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Exceptions>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.damagerow, exceptionRowsList2) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final View row;

            if (null == convertView) {
                row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.damagerow, null);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }

            TextView errorCode = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.error_code);
            TextView errorCodeval = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.error_code_val);
            TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            TextView descriptionVal = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.desc_val);
            damage1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.damageimage1);
            damage2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.damageimage2);
            damage3 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.damageimage3);
            damage4 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.damageimage4);

            damage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.damage_bg_default);
            damage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.damage_bg_default);
            damage3.setImageResource(R.drawable.damage_bg_default);
            damage4.setImageResource(R.drawable.damage_bg_default);
            errorCode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            errorCodeval.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            description.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            descriptionVal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            errorCode.setText("Error Code: ");
            errorCodeval.setText(""
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getAreaCode() + "-"
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getTypeCode() + "-"
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getSeverityCode()
                    .toString());
            description.setText("Description: ");
            descriptionVal.setText(""
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getAreaDesc() + " - "
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getTypeDesc() + " - "
                    + exceptionRowsList2.get(position).getSeverityDesc());

            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error_detail_list_bg);
            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.select_damage);
                    exceptionRowsList2.get(position).setTakeImage(true);
                    exceptionRowsList2.get(position).setDelete(true);
                }
            });
            return row;
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone please help me for this..? plz...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //3
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            //uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
            String imageFile = timeStamp + ".png";
            Log.w("Images From Sdcard", imageFile);
            damageList.add(imageFile);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + imageFile);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                //5
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String pathName = "/sdcard/" + imageFile;
            Resources res = getResources();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
            BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);

            switch(strDamages.length) {
            case 0 :
                damage1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;
            case 1 :
                damage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                i++;
                break;
            case 2 :
                damage3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                i++;
                break;
            case 3 :
                damage4.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                i++;
                break;
            }

            objDamages = damageList.toArray();
            strDamages = Arrays.copyOf(objDamages, objDamages.length, String[].class);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this).setMessage("Camera Activity Cancelled.")
                    .setTitle("status");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            dialogBuilder.create().show();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

### Camera Button Click event..

```
case R.id.camera_btn:
        if(exceptionRowsList.isEmpty()){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this).setMessage("No Exception Added")
                    .setTitle("Alert");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            dialogBuilder.create().show();
        }else{
            for (Exceptions exceptions : ede) {
                if(exceptions.getDelete()){
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                    break;
                }else{
                    //getlist(ede);
                    //exceptionRowsList.add(exceptions);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Have you used custom adapter?

Comment: yes i will post my code here.. Actually every row has 4 imageviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired output.. Actually, your imageviews in  `onActivitResult()` **has a reference of Last row of List**.

**Solution:**

Store image file path on array or list with position of click row of listview in `onActivityResult()` and just call `adapter.notifyDatasetChnaged()` from it.

Now on your adapter's `getView()` check position of item what you store in array at `onActivityResult()` and on this condition use a stored image file path of Bitmap to display in imageviews.

Comment: How to send the position of clicked row to onactivityResult? In my requirement onclick of camera button the captured images should be add to selected row.. But in onclicked row we havent used intent.. then how to send that value to onActivityResult?

Comment: Use any static variable to store values when listitem clicked and retrieve values from it in onActivityResult().

Comment: @user370305 Thanks for your Answer.!and user1441341 Thanks for Asking this Que :)